# WordPress on Apache behind nginx using letsencypt issue with loginizer/limit login attempts

Tags: login, docker

Similar to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58699582/wordpress-on-dokcer-using-loginiser-limit-login-attempts-reloaded-using-nginx-an

I can't figure out why loginizer and limit login attempts plugins keep kicking me out!

I detected that every time the nginx container restarts itself, the loginizer seems to store an attempt. I can also see this when using the site. When I restart docker suddenly my session is lost and WP asks me to login again.

This happens even if the user is not logged in, so when the user wants to log in the site is kicking them out for minutes or even hours depending how many times nginx restarted.

I don't know what else to say I'm a bit lost here because I can't debug the issue.